# jquery сдвинуть влево див

Tags: jquery, css

Есть такой кусок кода:

```
   $( ".left" ).click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".slideritems").css("margin-left", "-268px");
    });
```

при нажатии на кнопку весь див должен двигаться влево на 268рх, но не разово, а каждый раз, при нажатии дальше и дальше. Подскажите как это реализовать? чего то не могу найти ответ нигде

Answer (score 1):

С разметкой было бы проще, но и так сойдет:

```js
let currentDisplacement = 0;
 
$('.left').click(() => {
  currentDisplacement -= 268;
  
  console.log(currentDisplacement);
  
  $('.slideritems').css('margin-left', currentDisplacement);
});
```

```css
.slideritems {
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="slideritems"></div>
</div>
<button class="left">Click</button>
```